# The parameter passed to Ajax request has its spaces replaced with plus

Tags: jquery

I am making an Ajax request from jQuery. For some reason when the facetValue has a space in between it is encoding as a plus symbol. For get hybrid car is sent as hybrid+car and because of this my return value is nothing. Any idea what's happening?

---

```
function fetchResults(facetname,facetValue){
  $.ajax({url:"usageSearch.jsp",
    data:{searchquery:querystring,facetValue:facetValue,facetname:facetname},
    success:function(result){
      var usages=$.parseJSON(result);           
    });
}
```

Comment: Spaces must be encoded in either the URL or the request body, so that's normal behavior. Your server side should be able to decode the data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your request is send by GET try using POST:

```
$.ajax({url:"usageSearch.jsp",
    type : 'POST',
    data:{searchquery:querystring,facetValue:facetValue,facetname:facetname},
    success:function(result){
      var usages=$.parseJSON(result);           
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the data is being url encoded, this is normal procedure. You must decode it before working with it. In PHP that can be done like this:

```
$decoded_data = urldecode( $rawdata );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
url:escape("usageSearch.jsp"),
```

and

```
data:{searchquery:escape(querystring),facetValue:escape(facetValue),facetname:escape(facetname)}
```